# Get call using 'requests' library in Python 3.10 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-requests, proxy

I am trying to execute a REST get call using 'requests' library, and i am using python 3.10 on ubuntu

But I get the exception:
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXX', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: XXX (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable')))

I set environment variables in persistence file .bashrc :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpwlA.png)  and I added HTTP_PROXY variable too.

I tried sending proxies variable in the request but I get the same exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjfeS.png)

In the requests library documentation I coun't find any information about this exception.

Comment: When I pass the verify parameter  e.g.  r = session.get(url_root['api'], verify=False, headers=headers) , sometimes I get this error:  (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:997)')))

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'

try:
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
except AttributeError:
    # no pyopenssl support used / needed / available
    pass
```

Then call: r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=3, verify=False)